# Finding closed form of finite product

Tags: probability

I would like to find a closed form for the product

$$\frac{1}{m^a}\cdot\frac{1}{(m+1)^a}\cdots\frac{1}{(m+k-1)^a}.$$

I was given the hint to use the fact that $$\frac{1}{(m+r)^a} = \frac{1}{m^a} \cdot\frac{1}{(1+(r/m))^a}.$$

Are there any formulas for simplifying products of this sort?

The above quantity is the probability of an event Wm, where m is a natural number. I am asked to find P(Wm i.o.) = P(limsup Wm) as a function of a, for some fixed k. I know I need to sum the probabilities of the Wms and use the Borel Cantelli Lemma, but I'm not exactly sure how to make that happen.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is your task to find the closed form, or is it to solve some other problem?  There are certainly closed forms for the expression listed, but none of them are really likely to come from the given hint...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  the goal is to use this to solve a larger problem.  It is a probability theory question that I believe I can solve if I can get this into closed form.  The hint does not necessarily need to be used.

Comment: I suggest posting up the precise problem you've been given and the work you've done on it so far; that's much more likely to get you a useful answer than trying to work things out from the little subproblem you've selected.

Answer (score 1):

The product can be written in terms of a binomial coefficient and a factorial:
$$
\left[\binom{m+k-1}{k}k!\right]^{-a}
$$
or a ratio of factorials:
$$
\left[\frac{(m-1)!}{(m+k-1)!}\right]^a
$$
It might help to provide the context for the bigger question.

Comment: The bigger context of the question is that this quantity is the probability of an event Wm.  I am asked to find P(Wm i.o.) = P(limsup Wm).  I know I need to sum the probabilities of the Wms and use the Borel Cantelli Lemma, but I'm not exactly sure how to make that happen.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to do, but do you need to compute when $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left[\frac{(m-1)!}{(m+k-1)!}\right]^a$$ is finite or infinite?